# how can i use this variable outside it's loop?

Tags: java, declare

when i try to use the variable "encryptionKey" outside the loop or if-statement it's declared in, it throws a compile error "cannot find symbol".. any idea?

```
else if (inputPlainResultArray.length == 4 || inputPlainResultArray.length == 9 || inputPlainResultArray.length == 16)
{
   char[] encryptionKey = inputPlainResultArray;
   System.out.print("Encryption Key: ");
   System.out.print(encryptionKey);
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println();
   System.exit(0);

}
}
}
```

Comment: Those variable is out of scope.

In java the scope is restricted to {}.

Just move that variable declaration to top, so that they available further.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the scope of that `variable` is in the curly braces of the `loop`/`if` statement. You cannot use it like this. Instead declare it outside and use it.

In your case it will look something like this:

```
char[] encryptionKey = null;
if (...)
...
else if (inputPlainResultArray.length == 4 || inputPlainResultArray.length == 9 || inputPlainResultArray.length == 16)
{
    encryptionKey = inputPlainResultArray;
    System.out.print("Encryption Key: ");
    System.out.print(encryptionKey);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it's *local variable*, which means you can't access it outside the scope where it's declared.
You should take a look [on which types of variables exists in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

In your particular case you may use *instance variable*, so you either declare `char[] encryptionKey` outside the method:

```
 public class YourClass{
   char[] encryptionKey;
   // other methods, fields, etc.
}
```

and you'll be able to use this variable in any place in this class, or declare inside the method, bit outside the `else-if` scope:

```
char[] encryptionKey = null;
if (...){}

else if (...){
char[] encryptionKey = inputPlainResultArray;
}
```

so it'll be visible for all entities inside this particular method.

Answer (score 1):

create the variable outside of the method

```
char[] encryptionKey;
```

inside of the method then you can have

```
encryptionKey = ...
```

the only problem is if you try to call it before you initialize the variable, so be careful, or take precautions such as `if(encryptionKey==null) return;`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variable "encryptionKey" from outside the loop because you have declared it inside the loop.
Move the declaration outside and it will work.

```
char[] encryptionKey;    
else if (inputPlainResultArray.length == 4 || inputPlainResultArray.length == 9 || inputPlainResultArray.length == 16)
{

             encryptionKey = inputPlainResultArray;
             ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **break** keyword, not System.exit(0);

```
if(condition){
        //do something
        break;
    }
```

Comment: This is for your second question